# Align text center on mui's textfield

Tags: javascript, css, material-ui

Here is what I want:

[image]

Here is my result:

[image]

I try to assign the style to my input props, but no luck, any ideas? Thanks.

```
<TextField
    key={'verifyKey_'+i} 
    multiline={false}
    InputProps={{
        textAlign: 'center',
        disableUnderline: true, 
        style: {
            color: 'red', 
            textAlign: 'center'
        }
    }}
    style={{
        height: '50px',
        width: '50px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'}}/>
```

Comment: why you want to style input prop instead you can css attribute selector to style your element

Answer (score 2):

Using flexbox and replace `textAlign: 'center'` with `alignItems: 'center'`:

```
{
    height: '50px',
    width: '50px',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is essentially correct, you just need to lower case "InputProps" to "inputProps". Casing is important here.

```
inputProps={{ style: {textAlign: 'center'} }}
```

See also https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/5139

Answer (score 0):

You are using
width: '50px'

But you had it to 100%
width: '100%'

To make textAlign property worked properly..

If above wouldn't worked then add one more style to specify more precise
display:block for your text field.